# xtra alignment tab has been changed to \cr?

Tags: tables

I get the error mentioned in the title of the question. Can you help me please ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{ l c c c r }
$R_L (\Omega)$  &$ V_L (V)$ & $I_L (mA)(experimental)$ & $I_L (mA)(actual)$ & Percent Error (%)\\

$\infty$ & 4.99 & 0 &0 & 0 \\

980 &3.74 & 3.8  & 3.91 & 2.81\\

320 & 2.48 & 7.6 & 7.79 & 2.45\\

99.4 & 1.16 & 11.7&11.89 & 1.60 \\

0 & 0 & 15.1 & 15.5 & 2.58 \\

\end{tabular} \\

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. **Hint** The very first line ;-)

Comment: End the first line of your table with `\ \ `

Comment: **2nd Hint** The percent char in the first table row

Comment: You need to "escape" the `%` symbol in `Percent Error (%)`, i.e., write it as `\%`. That way, LaTeX won't treat it as start-of-comment directive and, as a result, also recognize the subsequent line break directive, `\\ `.

Answer (score 2):

You have the `%` without `\%`. Here is a quick solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{ l c c c r }
$R_L (\Omega)$  &$ V_L (V)$ & $I_L (mA)(experimental)$ & $I_L (mA)(actual)$ & Percent Error (\%)\\

$\infty$ & 4.99 & 0 &0 & 0 \\

980 &3.74 & 3.8  & 3.91 & 2.81\\

320 & 2.48 & 7.6 & 7.79 & 2.45\\

99.4 & 1.16 & 11.7&11.89 & 1.60 \\

0 & 0 & 15.1 & 15.5 & 2.58

\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

As a reference, consider remembering the following special `escape` characters referenced from [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/).

[image]